# Debugging in developer tools always step into jquery file

Tags: javascript, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I am new to this whole javascript development. I am debugging in chrome developer tools, I know that F11 will step into the function, but what am doing is clicking F10 so I can just go over my code and see what happens. But what happens is that the debugger always go to jquery file, and then I have to go back to my file, put a breakpoint then click F8 to go back to my file.

How do I step through the code in my file, without being transferred into jquery code inside jquery.js file?

any help would be apreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can right click on the jquery.js file and select "blackbox script". This will cause this file to be ignored by the debugger

Answer (score 0):

You can use :
Step out of current function (shift + F11) or (click on the below button)

[image]

Comment: Isn't this the same functionality as F10?

Comment: No, F10 is step over next function

Comment: You mean shift F11 in the jquery file?

Comment: If you can provide more details, that will be helpful

Comment: You mean shift F11 in the jquery file? Yes .

Comment: see the following doc https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/step-code